# Chaining asynchronous function calls in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

So I'm fairly new to JavaScript and aware of asynchronous functions calls. I have done quite a bit of research and found that if you want to run asynchronous calls in succession of one another, you can use callback functions and promises. Now I have come to understand how both of these implementations are useful if you are running just a few asynchronous functions. I'm trying to tackle a completely different animal; at least to my knowledge. I'm currently building a site that needs to appear as if it's writing text to itself. Just to clue everyone here in to my JS code, here is the function that writes to the webpage (I'm fairly new so if you think you have a better solution, an example with a small description would be appreciated):

```js
function write(pageText, elementId, delay) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var charCount = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (charCount > pageText.length) {
      return;
    } else {
      element.innerHTML = pageText.substr(0, charCount++);
    }
  }, delay);
}

write("This is an example", 'someRandomDiv', 100);
```

```html
<div id="someRandomDiv">

</div>
```

With this I'm trying to write a line of text to a webpage one line after another. Essentially I'm use to writing code like such in Java and C#:

```
function writePassage()
{ 
    var passage=["message one", "message two", "... message n"];
    for(var i = 0; i<passage.length; i++)
    {
        write(passage[i], 'someRandomDiv', 100);
    }
}
```

Obviously since this won't work because the for loop in wirtePassage() will finish executing  before just one or two of the asynchronous function calls end. I'm asking if there is a sane solution to this error where I have n asynchronous calls, and I need to have one perform before the next one is triggered. It's worth mentioning that I don't want to just run this loop above and add another variable that just keeps track of how long I should delay each passage that will be written. I would prefer if there was a programmatic way that forces the execution of the function before the next one is called. Thanks for reading this monster question!

Comment: *"this won't work"* isn't a proper explanation of what it does differently than expected or what errors are thrown. See [ask]

Comment: https://chainyjs.bevry.me may be of interest to you

Comment: FYI - You forgot to clear the interval: `var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (charCount > pageText.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      element.innerHTML = pageText.substr(0, charCount++);
    }
  }, delay);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things you'll need to do to get this working.

First, your `write` function will need an asynchronous interface.  As you mentioned it could either take a callback or return a promise.  Taking a callback would look something like:

```
function write(pageText, elementId, delay, callback)
{
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var charCount=0;

  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(charCount>pageText.length)
    {
      clearInterval(interval);
      callback();
    }
    else
    {
      element.innerHTML = pageText.substr(0,charCount++);
    }
  }, delay);
}
```

That calls `callback` when the full `pageText` has been written into `element`.  Note that it also clears your interval timer when it's done, which avoids an event loop leak.

Then, you'll need to chain your asynchronous calls using this callback.  You can do this quite cleanly with a library such as [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
function writePassage()
{
  var passage=["message one", "message two", "... message n"];
  async.series(passage.map(function(text){
    return function(done){
      write(text, 'someRandomDiv', 100, done);
    };
  }));
}
```

But it's also not so much trouble to do by hand:

```
function writePassage()
{
  var passage=["message one", "message two", "... message n"];

  var writeOne = function() {

    if (!passage.length) return;

    var text = passage.shift();

    write(text, 'someRandomDiv', 100, writeOne);
  }

  // Kick off the chain.
  writeOne();
}
```

That's just asynchronous recursion.  Welcome to JavaScript. :)

A promise-based solution can also be pretty clean.  First you need to *return* a promise from `write`:

```
function write(pageText, elementId, delay)
{
  return new Promise(resolve) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var charCount=0;

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(charCount>pageText.length)
      {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve();
      }
      else
      {
        element.innerHTML = pageText.substr(0,charCount++);
      }
    }, delay);
  }
}
```

Then you can create a *chain* of promises via reduction:

```
function writePassage()
{
  var passage=["message one", "message two", "... message n"];

  passage.reduce(function(chain, text) {
    return chain.then(function(){
      return write(text, 'someRandomDiv', 100, writeOne);
    });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Comment: holy carp what a nice answer! +1 for `caolan/async` library

Comment: This is by far one of the best answers i have ever received on stack. Thanks for the rich and detailed answer!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Bo's answer, here is how you would do it with promises (because promises are awesome!). It is a bit more advanced, but I also find it more elegant (array method call on strings, reduce).

I also used arrow functions. If you need to support old browsers, you may want to replace them with regular functions.

```js
// Return a promise resolved after time ms.
var wait = (time) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));

function write(pageText, elementId, delay){
  // Fetch the element.
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  // Empty the element.
  element.innerHTML = '';
  // Reduce on each character of pageText with a resolved promise
  // as a initialiser, and return the resulting promise.
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(pageText, (promise, char) => {
     // Chain to the previous promise.
     return promise
       // First wait delay ms.
       .then(() => wait(delay))
       // Then add the current character to element's innerHTML.
       .then(() => element.innerHTML += char);
  }, Promise.resolve());
}


var messages = ["message one", "message two", "... message n"];
messages.reduce((promise, message) => {
  return promise
    // Write current message.
    .then(() => write(message, "the-element", 100))
    // Wait a bit after each messages.
    .then(() => wait(400));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

```html
<div id="the-element"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't make this the suggested solution but your comment also helped me quite a bit with understanding other implementations with a working example! I greatly appreciate the effort you put into your answer!